# Getting error cannot convert type actionresult to viewresult in unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am creating a test project in MVC 5.

I am getting error

`Error  1   Cannot convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion`

Here is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void LoginTest()
    {

        // Arrange
        Mock<IAccountService<ApplicationUser>> membership = new Mock<IAccountService<ApplicationUser>>();

        var logonModel = new LoginViewModel() { UserName = null, Password = null };
        obj = new AccountController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = obj.Login(logonModel,"") as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewName, "Index");
        Assert.IsFalse(obj.ModelState.IsValid);
        Assert.AreEqual(obj.ModelState[""],"The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
```

And my controller action is following for which i m testing

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _accountService.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

            if (user != null )
            {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

EDIT: I am getting error in the test method on this line `obj.Login(loginviewmodel,"") as ViewResult` as the Login action is returning `Task<ActionResult>` type and I am casting it as `ViewResult`.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: It was not working because I was testing on a `async` method with a testmethod which do not have async keyword. As my Login method returns `Task` I have to set the return type of my test method as `Task` followed by an `async` keyword and call the method with await keyword. And it works.

Comment: Can you put your solution in the form of an answer, with the code you used?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @BrendanHannemann You can check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Login_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var logonModel = new LoginViewModel() { UserName = "Admin", Password = "admin123" };

        // Validate model state start
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(logonModel, null, null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        //set validateAllProperties to true to validate all properties; if false, only required attributes are validated.
        Validator.TryValidateObject(logonModel, validationContext, validationResults, true);
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
        // Validate model state end


        // Act

        var result = await controller.Login(logonModel, null) as RedirectToRouteResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Home", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
    }
```

This was the solution for my problem.  It will work for async methods. You have to change return type of  the action to `async Task` and call the method followed by `await` keyword.

To use the validation methods, add a using statement for `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: Can you please help me in fixing this issue; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965727/testing-user-if-he-has-a-specific-authority-using-authorizeasync-in-xunit-unit