# Testing user if he has a specific authority using AuthorizeAsync() in Xunit-Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit.net, asp.net-core-identity

**The question has been Updated for better explanation to the issue I have,**

Simply I have this controller,

```
    [Authorize]
    public class IdeaManagementController : Controller
    {
        private IIdeaManagementService _ideaManagementService;

        private ITenantService _tenantService;

        private ITagService _tagService;

        private IEmployeeIdeaCategoryService _ideaManagementCategoryService;

        private static PbdModule _modul = PbdModule.IdeaManagement;

        IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

        public IdeaManagementController(
            IIdeaManagementService ideaManagementService,
            ITenantService tenantService,
            ITagService tagService,
            IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
            IEmployeeIdeaCategoryService ideaManagementCategoryService)
        {
            _ideaManagementService = ideaManagementService;
            _tenantService = tenantService;
            _tagService = tagService;
            _authorizationService = authorizationService;
            _ideaManagementCategoryService = ideaManagementCategoryService;
        }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IdeaCoordinator()
    {
        if (!await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IdeaManagement_Coordinator"))
        {
            return new ChallengeResult();
        }
        var ideas = _ideaManagementService.GetByIdeaCoordinator(_tenantService.GetCurrentTenantId());
        return View(ideas);
    }
}
```

and simply I need to test the retrned viewResult of the action method IdeaCoordinator but I couldn't simply because if the _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync validation Method, **I tried to mock the method but simply I couldn't because it is an Extension Built In Method** , then I tried to make a work around solution by creating a new Interface that implements IAuthorizationService and Mock that customized Interface like that

```
public interface ICustomAuthorizationService : IAuthorizationService
{
    Task<bool> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, string policyName);
}


public IAuthorizationService CustomAuthorizationServiceFactory()
{
   Mock<ICustomAuthorizationService> _custom = new Mock<ICustomAuthorizationService>();
    _custom.Setup(c => c.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), "IdeaManagement_Coordinator")).ReturnsAsync(true);
    return _custom.Object;
}
```

and Inject it to while I am calling the controller constructor and then I found myself like that :

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
public async void IdeaManager_Should_Return_ViewResult(int _currentTenanatID)
{
    // Arrange ..
    _IdeaManagementControllerObject = new IdeaManagementController
                                      (IdeaManagementServiceMockFactory(_currentTenanatID),
                                      TenantServiceMockFactory(_currentTenanatID),
                                       TagServiceMockFactory(),
                                       AuthorizationServiceMockFactory(),
                                       EmployeeIdeaCategoryServiceMockFactory());
    // Act 
    var _view = await _IdeaManagementControllerObject.IdeaCoordinator() as ViewResult;

    // Assert 
    Assert.IsType(new ViewResult().GetType(), _view);
}
```

I expected different results because I marked the return result to be true just to ignore this line of code and continue to the Viewresult but while I debugged my Test Method again the compiler got into the validation message as it didn't feel the changes I did on the AuthorizeAsync Method result ..
[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

**==Solution==**

**Intro :**

“We can not solve our problems with the same level of thinking that created them” - Albert Einstein. and with this adorable saying I would like to inform that I spent about 1 week for solving this problem until I felt it will never solved at this moment, I spent hours of investigation, but after reading an article and after changing the way of thinking , the solution came in 30 mins.

**Problem at a glance :**

Simply, I was trying to unit test the written above action method, and I have a serious problem related with that I couldn't mock the method "AuthorizeAsync" and simply because it is a built in extension method and because of extension method nature as static method it can never be mocked with the traditional way of mocking classes.

**Solution in Details :**

To be able to mock this action method I created a static class that contains static delegates and with those delegates I will mock or as it can be said "Wrap" my extension method by a replacement of my static delegates in my unit test class as following.

```
public static class DelegateFactory
{
    public static Func<ClaimsPrincipal, object, string, Task<bool>> AuthorizeAsync =
        (c, o, s) =>
        {
            return AuthorizationServiceExtensions.AuthorizeAsync(null, null, "");
        };
}

public Mock<IAuthorizationService> AuthorizationServiceMockExtensionFactory()
{
    var mockRepository = new Moq.MockRepository(Moq.MockBehavior.Strict);
    var mockFactory = mockRepository.Create<IAuthorizationService>();
    var ClaimsPrincipal = mockRepository.Create<ClaimsPrincipal>();
    mockFactory.Setup(x => x.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
    return mockFactory;
}
```

and at my test method I just called the mocked object in the controller constructor instantiation.

```
    [Fact]
    public async void IdeaCoordinator_When_AuthroizedUser_IsNotNull_But_IdeaManagement_Manager_Authorized_Return_View()
    {
       // Arrange
        int approvedByID = data.GetTenantByID(1).TenantId;
        _IdeaManagementControllerObject = new IdeaManagementController
                                          (IdeaManagementServiceMockFactory().Object,
                                          TenantServiceMockFactory().Object,
                                           TagServiceMockFactory().Object,
                                           AuthorizationServiceMockExtensionFactory().Object,
                                           EmployeeIdeaCategoryServiceMockFactory().Object);
        //Act
        IdeaManagementServiceMockFactory().Setup(m => m.GetByIdeaCoordinator(approvedByID)).Returns(data.GetCordinatedEmpIdeas(approvedByID));
        ViewResult _view = await _IdeaManagementControllerObject.IdeaCoordinator() as ViewResult;
        var model = _view.Model as List<EmployeeIdea>;
        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(3, model.Count);
        Assert.IsType(new ViewResult().GetType(), _view);
    }
```

and as it said, The single greatest cause of happiness is gratitude.I would like to thank Stephen Fuqua for his brilliant solution and article , http://www.safnet.com/writing/tech/2014/04/making-mockery-of-extension-methods.html

Thank you everyone :) !

Comment: But your test expects a challenge result. Which according to method under test happens when use is not authorized. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Show the controller constructor as well. there are a lot of dependencies that have to be mocked for the test. (code smell) but need to see how those dependencies are injected to be able to provide you with an answer

Comment: The question has been updated by editing the Controller's Constructor and also the Constructor of the targeted Mocked Class.

Comment: I tried to mock the method like that :  _authorizationService.Setup(h => h.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal>(), "IdeaManagement_Coordinator")).ReturnsAsync(true); ... but then I got an exception as AuthorizeAsync is a static method !

Comment: I know :( Do you have any suggestion to mock this method ?

Comment: Abstract it behind an instance service. I had assumed that it was not static based on your code.

Comment: I would be so grateful if you can show how to do that with an example !

Answer (score 10):

Mock the necessary dependencies for the test. The method under test makes use of `IAuthorizationService`,`IIdeaManagementService`,and `ITenantService`. Everythign else is not needed for this particular test.

Coupling your code to 3rd party code you don't own and control makes it difficult to test. My suggestion is to abstract that behind an interface you control so you have that flexibility. So change out `IAuthorizationService` for your own abstraction.

```
public interface ICustomAuthorizationService {
     Task<bool> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, string policyName);
}
```

The implementation would wrap the actual authorization service that uses the extension method

```
public class CustomAuthorizationService: ICustomAuthorizationService {
    private readonly IAuthorizationService service;

    public CustomAuthorizationService(IAuthorizationService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Task<bool> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, string policyName) {
        return service.AuthorizeAsync(user, policyName);
    }
}
```

Make sure to register your wrapper. for example.

```
services.AddSingleton<ICustomAuthorizationService, CustomAuthorizationService>();
```

If Identity is already added to service collection then the `IAuthorizationService` will get injected into your custom service when resolved.

So now for your test you can mock the interfaces you control and not have to worry about breaking 3rd party code.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
public async void IdeaManager_Should_Return_ViewResult(int _currentTenanatID) {
    // Arrange ..
    var ideaManagementService = new Mock<IIdeaManagementService>();
    var tenantService = new Mock<ITenantService>();
    var authorizationService = new Mock<ICustomAuthorizationService>();
    var sut = new IdeaManagementController(
                     ideaManagementService.Object,
                     tenantService.Object,
                     null,
                     authorizationService.Object,
                     null);

     authorizationService
         .Setup(_ => _.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), "IdeaManagement_Coordinator"))
         .ReturnsAsync(true);

     tenantService
         .Setup(_ => _.GetCurrentTenantId())
         .Returns(_currentTenanatID);

     var ideas = new //{what ever is your expected return type here}
     ideaManagementService
         .Setup(_ => _.GetByIdeaCoordinator(_currentTenanatID))
         .Returns(ideas);

    // Act 
    var _view = await sut.IdeaCoordinator() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(_view);
    Assert.IsType(typeof(ViewResult), _view);
    Assert.AreEqual(ideas, view.Model);
}
```

This is one example of the draw backs of extension methods as they are static and difficult to test if they hide dependencies.

Comment: authorizationService
         .Setup(_ => _.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<IPrincipal>(), "IdeaManagement_Coordinator"))
         .ReturnsAsync(true);   ===>> it will throw an exception like what I tried before !

Comment: IAuthorizationService is a built in interface you can get by callingg the NameSpace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization ..

Comment: what is your opinion about moles as a way to mock Extension methods ?

Comment: public static Task<bool> AuthorizeAsync(this IAuthorizationService service, ClaimsPrincipal user, string policyName); ==>> this is the AuthorizeAsync body and as you can it is an extension method !

Comment: it is built-in method provided by the .Net Frameowkr itself of course I can't know what is going on under the hood !

Comment: The source code is online. But that is the very reason we don't couple our code to 3rd part stuff. makes it difficult to test. My suggestion is to abstract that behind an interface you control so you have that flexibility.

Comment: I updated my Question again one more time , May I ask you to read it again ?

Comment: @FreedomDeveloper, Don't inherit you custom service from the 3rd part. you will end up with  same problem. wrap 3rd party with your implementation.

Comment: If I did that I will need to make an object of the CustomClass as a parameter in the Controller constructor and I don't want to change anything in the code classes unfortunately .

Comment: Then I guess you are stuck. Not much else I can suggest if that is the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138833/discussion-between-freedomdeveloper-and-nkosi).

Comment: May I ask you to have a look on the solution I added in my updated question ? - and please if you like the solution, I would be so grateful if you rate it so the administration can remove banning me from writing more questions ?!

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this issue as well while developing an ASP.NET Core API. My situation was less complex, so not sure if the same solutions is applicable for you.

Here is my solution

`IAuthorizationService` has two methods that are not extensions. One can assume (and I verified) that the extensions are just helpers and will call either one of these methods.

```
Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement> requirements);
Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, string policyName);
```

So mocking `IAuthorizationService` for me was as simple as doing the following:

```
var authorizeService = new Mock<IAuthorizationService>();
authorizeService.Setup(service => service.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(AuthorizationResult.Success);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to markbeij's answer, you must also instantiate the ClaimsPrincipal user (and possibly its identity) otherwise a null reference exception will be raised. This is a problem I experienced (ASP.NET Core 5) and here's my solution to anyone else experiencing this problem:

```
// Arrange
var mockAuthorizationService = new Mock<IAuthorizationService>();
mockAuthorizationService
    .Setup(a => a.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(AuthorizationResult.Success)
    .Verifiable();

// Instantiate User
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal();

// Add identity if you need to access the User.Identity
httpContext.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity());

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
{
    HttpContext = httpContext
};

var controller = new AccountController(mockAuthorizationService.Object);

// Act
var result = await controller.Index();

// Assert
mockAuthorizationService.Verify(a => a.AuthorizeAsync(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Thanks for this addition. If you could just edit your code in order to place "controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext" after the var controller = new ... it would be perfect. I believe this is a typo.